# Equivalent to Mac's help search on Windows?

Tags: windows, mac, search

Is there a Windows equivalent (native or utility) that will allow me to [search through the active application's menu hierarchy](https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/use-the-macos-help-menu/) for a command and show me matches as I type? No launchy/Spotlight-like launchers or other utilities that I know of do this.

[image: Equ]